# How do I enter a system of differential equations in the Manipulate command?

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I need to use the `Manipulate[]` command in *Mathematica* to identify the parameter `N` for which the Holling Tanner model:

$dx/dt=x(1-x/7)-(6xy)/(7+7x), dy/dt=0.2y(1-Ny/x)$

will have a limit cycle. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) and [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

```
Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]/7) - (6 x[t] y[t])/(7 + 7 x[t]),
    y'[t] == 1/5 y[t] (1 - n y[t]/x[t]), x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, 
    {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}];
 ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 3}}, AspectRatio -> 1],
 {n, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Using [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

```
Clear[n]
solP = ParametricNDSolve[{
   x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]/7) - (6 x[t] y[t])/(7 + 7 x[t]),
   y'[t] == 1/5 y[t] (1 - n y[t]/x[t]), x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, 
   {t, 0, 10}, n]

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[{x[n][t], y[n][t]} /. solP, {n, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 3}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
Manipulate[sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]/7)
- (6 x[t]*y[t])/(7 (1 + x[t])), y'[t] == 1/5 y[t] (1 - n y[t]/x[t]), 
x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 200}];
Grid[{{Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 200}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.003]}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Tiny}], 
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 200}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.003]}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Tiny}]}}], 
{{n, 0.08, TraditionalForm[n]}, 0.08, 1.3, 0.0001}, 
FrameLabel -> {None, None, Style["Hopf Bifurcation", Bold, Medium], 
None}]
```

[image]